# Show context menu on right click High-chart v3.0.10

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, contextmenu

I am using bar chart of High-Chart API v3.0.10. I need show context menu on right click to show X and y axis value of bars. I am taking reffarnce of http://joekuan.wordpress.com/2011/05/11/making-highcharts-support-right-click-context-menu/   but not able to understand how to implement suggested changes in given link.

Answer (score 0):

I adivce to familiar with the customEvents.js plugin, which allows to add custom right click event.

http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/15/Custom-Events/